# Why is ubuntu, or any OS for that matter, giving me a blank syslinux screen? (USB)

Tags: boot, usb, syslinux

I'm getting a syslinux screen upon boot from USB, is there any way to avoid this? It's happening for any OS that I'm trying to install.

The exact message is: SYSLINUX 4.03 2010-10-22 EDD Copyright (C) 1994-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al

I've researched this and every response I've found has been tried with no success.

I'd love if someone could help me out, thanks.